# Hiveserver not found in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hive

When I starting serverHive2 in cmd ubunto I have:

```
/local/hive/lib/hive-jdbc-2.1.0-standalone.jar!/hive-webapps/hiveserver2/ to /tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-10002-hiveserver2-_-any-/webapp
19/04/25 20:03:42 [Thread-12]: WARN thrift.ThriftCLIService: XSRF filter disabled
19/04/25 20:03:42 [Thread-12]: INFO server.Server: jetty-7.6.0.v20120127
19/04/25 20:03:42 [Thread-12]: INFO handler.ContextHandler: started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/,null}
19/04/25 20:03:42 [Thread-12]: INFO server.AbstractConnector: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:10001
19/04/25 20:03:42 [Thread-12]: INFO thrift.ThriftCLIService: Started ThriftHttpCLIService in http mode on port 10001 path=/cliservice/* with 5...500 worker threads
19/04/25 20:03:42 [main]: INFO handler.ContextHandler: started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/,file:/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-10002-hiveserver2-_-any-/webapp/},jar:file:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-jdbc-2.1.0-standalone.jar!/hive-webapps/hiveserver2
19/04/25 20:03:42 [main]: INFO handler.ContextHandler: started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/static,jar:file:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-jdbc-2.1.0-standalone.jar!/hive-webapps/static}
19/04/25 20:03:42 [main]: INFO server.AbstractConnector: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:10002
19/04/25 20:03:42 [main]: INFO http.HttpServer: Started HttpServer[hiveserver2] on port 10002
```

shell of ubunto, It stays blocked and does not connect in beeline

```
beeline> !connect jdbc:hive2://localhost:10002/default

19/04/25 20:07:08 [main]: WARN jdbc.HiveConnection: Failed to connect to localhost:10002
Error: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10002/default: Invalid status 72 (state=08S01,code=0)
```

Comment: After starting HiveServer2 , check if it is going down for any reason. You may check if 10002 post is listening using commands "sudo netstat -nautpl | grep 10002 ". Also check if there is any error message logged in hiveserver2 log file while beeline is trying to connect to server.

Answer (score 0):

javier@javier-VirtualBox:/usr/local/hive/bin$ sudo netstat -nautlp | grep 10002
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10002           0.0.0.0:*               ESCUCHAR    19704/java

Where is hiveserver2 log file?